# How to make IE to work expectedly with regular expressions provided as function argument in split function?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

The following code works expectedly in all the major browsers like Firefox,Opera,Chrome,Safari etc, but shows unexpected result in IE 6,7,8 (the versions so far I have tested).

Objective: To split the string at the first underscore (_) resulting in the substrings "you" and "and_me".

IE shows only "you" part and the rest as undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var str = "you_and_me";
 var res = str.split(/_(.+)?/);
 alert(res);
</script>
```

Solution: What should I do to make IE work properly?

Comment: It splits into you,and,me- not the solution @hjpotter92

Comment: All jokes aside about making "...IE work properly", the only answer here is to code your own function to do the split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to support ancient versions of IE, then stop using `.split()` with a regex and just code your own split function that doesn't use a regex.  That should be way less trouble than trying to figure out what wonky regex differences an old version of IE has.

```js
function oneSplit(s, sep) {
    var result = [];
    var i = s.indexOf(sep);
    if (i !== -1) {
        result.push(s.slice(0, i));
        result.push(s.slice(i + 1));
    } else {
        result.push(s);
    }
    return result;
}

var str = "you_and_me";
var result = oneSplit(str, "_");

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

P.S. When I run your code in Chrome, I get an empty string at the end of the array which is probably not intended.

Comment: thank u @jfriend00, one vote from me, but this code still doesn't run in IE7.

Comment: I also wonder,in case of my code, that an extra empty string is created but couldn't figure out why :(

Comment: @rosemary - why do you think this doesn't work in IE7?  `JSON.stringify()` doesn't exist in IE7, but that is only for purposes of showing the output in the snippet, not part of the actual `split()` function.

Comment: @rosemary - Did this answer solve your issue?  If so, please mark an accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.

Comment: tnq..@jfriend00 coz, i tried to run it on IE 7, it does not show anything, but in firefox it is good :) but i want it to work in IE also..

Comment: @rosemary - as I said before, the function `oneSplit()` itself should work fine in IE7.  The demo would not work in IE7 only because `JSON.stringify()` does not exist in IE7, but that's only part of the demo (to display the result), not part of the actual solution you would use.

Comment: @rosemary - I just tried the `oneSplit()` function in IE7 and it works just fine.